# How to check if a python function is a Tornado generator

Tags: python, tornado, python-decorators

Given a function `foobar` how can I check that it's a generator that is expected by Tornado?

```
In [1]: from tornado import gen

In [2]: @gen.coroutine
   ...: def foobar():
   ...:     print 'boom'
   ...:
```

I wasn't able to find any properties, that could indicate that it's correctly decorated by a `gen.coroutine`

Comment: Maybe in `foobar.func_code.co_filename`

Comment: And then search for the word 'gen' in there? seems hacky but closer than anything else I've found

Comment: Seems very hacky and lame, which is why I commented instead of answering.  But I could not find anything better in python2

Comment: `'TracebackFuture' in foobar.func_code.co_names` still hacky but closer to happiness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no good way to detect this, and even if `@coroutine` were modified to set some attribute, this would fail in cases when multiple decorators are used (e.g. handlers may be decorated with both `@authenticated` and `@coroutine`, and the `@authenticated` decorator's wrapper will hide whatever `@coroutine` added)

Furthermore, many functions (including core Tornado methods like `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch` or most methods of `IOStream`) are not technically coroutines but they can be called as if they were. In most cases the most important question is not "is this a coroutine" but "does this return a `Future`". There is no way to determine this in Python without calling the function.

Comment: I ended up writing my own decorator, which decorated the function with tornado's coroutine, and added a flag that I could check. Not ideal, but provides a way for me to do all sorts of sanity checks when functions are passed around, **before** executing the function.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a satisfactory way to introspect it from the already existing decorator `gen.coroutine`.

I'm not sure if this is helpful for you, but if you have control over the specific decorator itself then  you may have the option of simply tacking on an attribute to the function itself.

```
>>> def my_gen_coroutine(f):
...     f = gen.coroutine(f)
...     f.is_a_tornado_generator = True
...     return f
... 
>>> @my_gen_coroutine
... def foobar():
...     print 'boom'
...     
>>> foobar.is_a_tornado_generator
True
>>> foobar()
boom
<tornado.concurrent.Future at 0x1397d50>
```

Of course, you would use `getattr(some_function, 'is_a_tornado_generator', False)` when you don't know if the attribute is there or not.

Comment: :( yeah, but I don't want to require the users of my library to use a custom decorator... though from my search online this is becoming the most plausible solution